# ASP.NET MVC using Azure AD for Authorization

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to understand Authorization filters using Azure AD(Entra ID) for Authentication and Authorization. I have three roles created in Azure with users assigned to those roles. The app is successfully using Azure for Authentication but the Authorization isnt working.

When I go to https://localhost:sslport/ and https://localhost:sslport/Dashboard it allows all three users access after authenticating agains MS. But if I go to https://localhost:sslport/Dashboard/Settings, https://localhost:sslport/Dashboard/Administrator or https://localhost:sslport/Dashboard/Poweruser I get access denied.

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "qualified.domain.name",
    "TenantId": "d1d5fe91-a895-45d7-964a-8ae51ff19d03",
    "ClientId": "ac748c0f-f4f1-4351-b317-977d2edb81e1",
    "CallbackPath": "/Signin-oidc",
    "SignoutcallbackUrl": "/Signout-oidc"
  },

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureADRoles
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
                options.AddPolicy("RequirePoweruserRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Poweruser"));
                options.AddPolicy("RequireUserRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));
            });

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                // Set RoleClaimType to "groups" to use Azure AD groups as roles
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "groups";
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddRazorPages()
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;

namespace AzureADRoles.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Poweruser,User")]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Policy = "RequireUserRole")]
        public IActionResult Settings()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdminRole")]
        public IActionResult Administrator()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Policy = "RequirePoweruserRole")]
        public IActionResult Poweruser()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the screencap of your Roles in AD.

Comment: Sorry, trying to figure out how to post a screen shot. It's 3am my time btw.

Comment: Is there any update on this question now? Per my understanding, we are trying to achieve a feature that, user who had admin role can access Administrator page, but others are not allowed. Similar to other pages. Pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement..

Answer (score 0):

I trust you are trying to realize role-based access control(RBAC), we had [a sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles) here.

We firstly need to have the Azure AD roles and assign to different users, then define and use the policy in the application.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options =>
{
    // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are available.
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
});

// Adding authorization policies that enforce authorization using Azure AD roles.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("mypolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("Tiny.AccessEndpoint"));
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Create Azure AD roles and [assign users or groups to this role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-add-app-roles-in-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-microsoft-entra-roles).

[image]

[image]